# Implementing oauth2 login with server and mobile app

Tags: android, facebook, oauth-2.0

I want to implement login with Facebook for my service(which can be accessed via web as well as a native android)

This is what I am doing for the web part:

1. User clicks on login to Facebook
2. It gets directed to fb's page , where it checks for credentials
3. It redirects to a page on my web service, with the details
4. Then, my own service creates an access token for its use, and sends it as a json output to client.

I would like to know how this can be achieved using android. If I use a web view inside my app, the user will have to login to Facebook (which I want to avoid). Instead, if he is logged in on Facebook using the Facebook app, it should directly go over to permissions.

If I use the native sdk for android, I don't know how to perform the redirect to my own server and generate an access token for my own website.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grant user access token for your website (via Dashboard -> Choose a platform), then you should implement login process provided by Facebook in your website, and under your application settings page (Under your Facebook Developer account page) enable your application for web.

Quick start: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Comment: how does this answer my question ?

Comment: Because why would you want to use webview to get user logged into his Facebook account where FB SDK provides you with a Native Android Login dialog (whether your user is logged in via FB application or not), and in case of the FB app not available, FB made a fall back that will provide your user with a dialog that has a webview to be able to login ... So, and based on what you said above (Which you are aware of), the only logic need is that you want to have your user to be logged in both your web site & on your native Android app, & that's why I provided you the steps to implement login on web

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in native android what you have done in web.

Just [Facebook Authentication for android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)

I have fallen under the same scenario as yours I have successfully implemented by using web service of my own.

```
 private void doFacebookLogin(View v) {
        final View snakeBarView = v;
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                Snackbar.make(snakeBarView, "Facebook Login Success", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                                if (response.getError() != null) {
                                    // handle error
                                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Success");
                                    try {
                                        String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                                        String emailId, id, name, profilePicture;
                                        if (json.isNull("id"))
                                            id = "";
                                        else
                                            id = json.getString("id");
                                        if (json.isNull("email"))
                                            emailId = id + "@facebook.com";
                                        else
                                            emailId = json.getString("email");

                                        if (json.isNull("name"))
                                            name = "";
                                        else
                                            name = json.getString("name");

                                        profilePicture = getString(R.string.fbProfilePicUrl) + id + "/picture?type=large";
                                        Registration registration = new Registration();
                                        registration.Name = name;
                                        registration.EmailId = emailId.toUpperCase();
                                        registration.ProfilePicture = profilePicture;
                                        registration.PhoneNumber = "";
                                        registration.Area = "";
                                        registration.Password = "";
                                        ghilliHelper.signupOrLoginPreStep(registration);
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }).executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Snackbar.make(snakeBarView, "Facebook Login Cancelled", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Snackbar.make(snakeBarView, "Facebook Login Error", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

After successfull facebook login get email id and call your service from app.

On your service.

Check the email id is exist or not

if email id does not exist create an account and return a JSON as success login

else return JSON as success login.

Web Service

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<string> SocialMediaLogin(Registration reg)
        {
            LoginResult logResult = new LoginResult();

            try
            {
                CloudTableClient tableclient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
                CloudTable table = tableclient.GetTableReference(_registrationTable);

                if (!table.Exists())
                {
                    logResult.Failure = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    TableQuery<Registration> query = new TableQuery<Registration>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, reg.EmailId.ToUpper()));
                    Registration reg_obj2 = new Registration();
                    IEnumerable<Registration> ienum_obj = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
                    if (ienum_obj.Count() != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var a in ienum_obj)
                        {
                            logResult.Success = true;
                            logResult.UserDetails = a;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RegistrationResult signupResult = await SocialMediaSignup(reg); //Create an Account
                        if (signupResult.Success)
                        {
                            logResult.Success = true;
                            logResult.UserDetails = signupResult.UserDetails;
                        }
                        else if (signupResult.Failure)
                        {
                            logResult.Failure = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                logResult.Failure = true;
            }
            var resultString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logResult);
            return resultString;
        }
```

Comment: at this part of your answer "Check the email id is exist or not", how do I make sure that its not a malicious post request to my service ?

Comment: @harvey_slash Good Question . You can create a AD token from certificate. In that case we can avoid the malicious post request.

Comment: any example for that ?